# Game chat lobby

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games

How would a game chat lobby be implemented in Google play game services.By a lobby i mean allows chat and inviting others users to play.
So far in the examples i have seen from Google (Button Clicker), invites start a room. What i need is one or later more central rooms that users can connect to and send messages and then initiate invites. Is this possible?
With random matching ,  the player may have to wait a while to get an opponent and invite friend on google+ , the friend needs the app installed and the app open to play.

Comment: It was probably down voted, as the "rules" say that questions should be Code specific, and the user should show that they've researched whatever they are trying to do, yet I've seen plenty of popular questions, that had absolutely no Code associated, and were easily understood by answerers and reviewers  (spelling error on purpose).  For your example, it is Not possible using Google Play Game Services, as there is no "meeting room" functionality currently built into the API.   You either try to form a room with specific players in mind, auto-match criteria, or combination of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, No at this time.  (follow up edit for below)

Google Play Services does not currently maintain a "meeting room" part to their API.  In order to have a lobby,  you would have to host it completely separate to the Google Game Services API's (but could have them login to their G+ accounts to gain access to your lobby.  But, as you stated, in order for a specific link up to occur, each player must have the other player in their circles, so even if players wanted to ask another player in the room to play, a process for adding them to their circle would need to exist within the lobby room portion of your application.)

Joining by Random play as currently implemented would still be faster than a lobby room, since as soon as a viable match is available, G+ will auto link up the players and send the start message.  For the lobby room with players already in their circle(s), the invitation system (combined with a quick email/sms) does still allow for fairly quick linkup of known players with each other.